# Android: Is it possible to only show mobile numbers (and not fax, home or business numbers, etc) from contact selection

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to filter out and allow the user to select contacts mobile numbers only from the list?

Current code:

```
    case R.id.contacts_button:
            Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contactsIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(contactsIntent, 1);
            return;
```

but this shows all type of phone numbers including fax, work, home and I'd prefer to see just mobile.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No I haven't, sorry.  You?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the cursor holding base contact data, and will loop through the phone numbers the contact has, can have multiple.

```
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Cursor cursor=ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

   while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
   String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
   String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
   if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
                // You know have the number so now query it like this
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
  null, 
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
      null, null); 
    while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
     String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
       phones.getColumnIndex( 
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
    } 
    phones.close(); 
   } 
 }
```